# How do I zip up my jar files

Tags: java, file, jar, executable-jar, zip

I want a zip file that contains my jar file program and only my jar file program.

I tried this converter: 
https://convertio.co/archive-converter/

but it just separated my jar file into classes?

Comment: Can you please rephrase what you're trying to do? As it stands, it looks like you want to zip a jar file, which is not a programming question.

Comment: A jar file is already a compressed archive. Looks like you are trying to zip something that is already zipped.

Comment: I want a zip file, with a jar file inside it

Comment: Then you should ask on SuperUser. Also, you should mention what operating system you're using. Also, why? As @Gautam said, a JAR is a zip file already.

Answer (score 3):

A .jar file already *is* a zip file (in that it’s contents follow the Zip file format), which would explain why your converter unzipped it.